# How to remove soft line break in the field that from styleRef in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, field-codes, linebreaks

I create a header in WORD 2013 that contain a field from my chapter style ref. The problem is chapter title has a soft line break, I want to remove it in header, how to do it?

[image: Here header from my chapter title]

Answer (score -1):

The only workaround I can think of is to write a *shadow header* without the soft brake line.

1. Create a new style named shadow_header based on the "Normal" style but with font color the same as the background and font size = 1.
2. Write title normally.
3. Following the title (or immediately before). Write, **without soft break lines** the same text as in the title.
4. Select this last text and define its style as **shadow_title**.
5. In the header, you can now refer to the shadow_title text and *voila*...